# When would I use function borrowing?

Tags: javascript

Function borrowing is borrowing the function from an object rather than redefining it; but why should I do it. We can have a generic function and objects can use them further. To be more precise; when would I use code #1 when I can code it like in code #2:

code #1

```
let car1 = {
  speed: 80,
  getSpeed: function () {
    return this.speed;
  },
};
let car2 = {
  speed: 60,
};
console.log(car1.getSpeed());
console.log(car1.getSpeed.call(car2));
```

code #2

```
function getSpeed() {
  return this.speed;
}
let car1 = {
  speed: 80,
}
let car2 = {
  speed: 60,
}
console.log(getSpeed.call(car1));
console.log(getSpeed.call(car2));
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Function borrowing is used when you already have a method defined for an object (either directly or via the prototype chain), and you want to be able to use it with a similar object that doesn't have that method defined.

This is the case in your code #1 -- rather than use prototypical inheritance or classes, the `getSpeed()` method was defined directly in `car1`. Rather than duplicate the code in `car2`, you can borrow from `car1`.

You wouldn't normally design things this way from scratch. Either you would use an ordinary function as in code #2, or you would make `car1` and `car2` inherit from the same prototype.

Function borrowing is usually just a workaround for poor initial design. You see it in code like

```
nodes = document.getElementsByClassName("foo");
result = [].prototype.map.call(nodes, someFunction);
```

because the `NodeList` prototype doesn't have its own `map()` function.

Comment: I think method borrowing is not related to polymorphism as we use it when we don't want to do inheriting.

Comment: Oh, now I understand. "borrowing" refers to the way he used the `car1` method with `car2`.

Answer (score 3):

As an addendum to Barmar's answer the third option you might consider is using a [`class`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes#field_declarations) to create object instances which share the same methods.

```js
class Car {

  constructor(speed) {
    this.speed = speed;
  }

  getSpeed() {
    return this.speed;
  }

}

console.log(new Car(80).getSpeed());
console.log(new Car(60).getSpeed());
```

Answer (score 1):

Benefits of using Code #1 (Function borrowing) vs Code #2 is, it lets you skip inheritance. In your example you are granting access of `car1.getSpeed()` to `car2`.

**Benefits are:**

1. Skipping a need for class inheritance
2. Reduce bugs with having 1 copy of the function vs copies floating around.

It is mostly used with native methods like `slice()` from `Array.prototype`

So if you have array like (but not exactly) structures, borrowing `slice()` from `Array.prototype` gives you access to the `.map`/`.filter` etc.

Practical example:

```js
function findS() {
  return Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments).filter( arg => arg.includes('s'))
}

console.log(findS("Tesla", "Mitsubishi", "Ford"))
```